# Oracle SQL query execution time - forever

Tags: sql, oracle

There is ONE select (about 40k rows). When I'm trying to execute it from admin profile (connection) there is no problem, it takes about 9,5 seconds to execute.

But then - if I want to execute it from different profile (and this profile has all privileges to select data from every table included to above mentioned query), it takes an eternity, I mean I waited 38 minutes to check if it completes, but no.

There's no bug, no popup from SQL Developer, in `v@session_longops` you can see that query is active in this session but nothing happens after all (only admin can execute it with success)

My question is - what can be the cause and where I can find a solution?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: details of the users (including grants); the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the tables; you SQL query; and the execution plans for both users.

Comment: What do you call a "profile"? Is it another database user? If so, how does that user access tables you're talking about? Is it via synonyms, by specifying owner's name (in front of every table), via database link(s), or ...?

Comment: Performance tuning questions need a lot of information about the tables, indexes, data, execution plans and so on, and can be quite hard to reproduce. From what you've told us, I would want to confirm that the two users (if that's what 'profiles' are - like Littlefoot I'm not familiar with those) are accessing the same tables, what the two execution plans were and why they were different.